# How do I get CMake to link with an external library?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to get CMake under CLion to build a simple program that links with the curl library.  From the command line it builds like this:

`gcc main.c -l curl`

I can't get CMake to link with the curl library however:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(http_examples_c C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(http_examples_c main.c)
target_link_libraries(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a)
```

How do I tell CMake to just link with the curl library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#overview), you need to tell CMake to link the library to a specific target you have already defined. Try something like this instead:

```
target_link_libraries(http_examples_c PUBLIC /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a)
```

As commented, you shouldn't need to put the *full* path to the curl library in your system path, unless you are trying to let CMake choose this curl library over *another* curl library that may also be in your system. Given your `gcc` command simply used `curl`, you could likely simplify this call to:

```
target_link_libraries(http_examples_c PUBLIC curl)
```

Comment: Just `target_link_libraries(http_examples_c PUBLIC curl)`

Comment: @KamilCuk Good catch, updated the answer.